# Trigonometric integral with cosinus

Tags: calculus

I cannot solve the equation below:
I know what I typed is wrong byt I can't understand where it went sour.

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(5x)} dx$$
$$\left[
\begin{align*}
5x=s\\
x=\frac{s}{5};
\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{1}5
\end{align*}
\right]
$$
$$
\frac{1}{5}\int \frac{1}{\cos (s)}\frac{\cos (s)}{\cos (s)}\,ds=
\frac{1}{5}\int \frac{\cos (s)}{\cos^2(s)}\,ds=\frac{1}{5}\int \frac{\cos (s)}{1-\sin^2(s)}\,ds
$$

$$\left[
\begin{align*}
\sin(s)=y\\
\frac{dy}{ds}=-\cos(s)
\end{align*}
\right]
$$

$$
\frac{1}{5} \cdot -\frac{1}{2}\int -\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{1+y} dy
$$
$$
\left[ -(-\ln(1-y) - \ln(1+y)\right]
=
\left[ \ln\frac{(1-y)}{(1+y)}\right]
=
\left[ \ln\frac{(1-\sin(s))}{(1+\sin(s))}\right]
=
\left[ \ln\frac{(1-\sin(5x))}{(1+\sin(5x))}\right]
$$

Comment: The standard term in English is "cosine" rather than "cosinus".

Comment: The derivative of sine is cosine, not minus-cosine, hence for $y=\sin s$ you should get $dy/ds = \cos s$, not $-\cos s$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that taking the derivative of
$$\ln\left(\frac{1-\sin(5x)}{1+\sin(5x)}\right)=\ln(\underbrace{1-\sin(5x)}_{>0})-\ln(\underbrace{1+\sin(5x)}_{>0})$$
we get
$$\frac{-5\cos(5x)}{1-\sin(5x)}-\frac{5\cos(5x)}{1+\sin(5x)}=
-\frac{10\cos(5x)}{1-\sin^2(5x)}=-\frac{10}{\cos(5x)}.$$
So you are not so far from the correct answer: you just forgot to consider the constant $\frac{1}{5} \cdot -\frac{1}{2}$ in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Have you met the $\sec$ function? That will make things a lot easier here. 
We have that $\sec y =\frac{1}{\cos y}$, therefore your integral becomes:
$$\int{\sec (5x) dx}$$Standard integration, while remembering to divide by the $5$, gives us $$\frac15\ln|\sec(5x)+\tan(5x)|+C$$

---

I believe your mistake is that $$y=\sin(s)\to\frac{dy}{ds}=\cos(s) \text{ rather than } (-\cos(s))$$

Comment: "Standard integration" is a little terse.

Comment: Nope, have not met them yet...

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, you can work this out with the unintuitive subsitution $u=\sin 5x$ directly.

$$x=\frac15\arcsin u,dx=\frac15\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}},\\\int\frac{dx}{\cos 5x}=\frac15\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac15\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}.
$$

The last integral is elementary, giving

$$\frac15\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}=\frac15\text{artanh }u=\frac15\text{artanh}(\sin 5x).$$

---

If you never heard of the hyperbolic functions, notice the similarity with the ordinary arc tangent, and check the [logarithm-based formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html). Of course, you get the same result with fraction decomposition.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here, but thank you. I'll be back later when I understand better :)

Comment: @Dovendyr: an ordinary change of variable followed by a "table lookup".

Answer (score 1):

**There is nothing wrong in your answer.**

Collecting your result, we indeed have

$$I=\frac15\left(-\frac12\right)\left[ \ln\frac{1-\sin(5x)}{1+\sin(5x)}\right]+C$$ which is correct as can be checked by differentiation.

It is not even necessary to consider absolute values, as the numerator and denominator are non-negative.

---

Just a little reproach on you: you didn't clearly show the links between the partial results.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry, where is this 5 coming from?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by showing the link between partial results?

Comment: @Dovendyr: sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust: noproblem!